# Minimum version for syscall write

Tags: linux-kernel, syscalls

Which is the first version of the linux-kernel implementing the system call write? (sys_write)

Comment: That's a lot harder (one of the very first kernels :-) )

Comment: @ThomasDickey ok. maybe version 1.x?

Comment: Linux started before 1.0 (I've used it since some 0.9x).  See [1.0 page](http://www.oldlinux.org/Linux.old/docs/history/1.0.html).

Comment: "***one*** of the first"?  Are you kidding?  The "write" system call was in Unix in the mid 1970s, before Linux even existed.

Answer (score 3):

As you might expect, given that the `write` system call is a staple of Unix-style kernels, Linux had it as soon as it was “grown up” enough to be a kernel. You can see its implementation in [version 0.01](http://www.oldlinux.org/Linux.old/kernel/0.00/linux-0.01/fs/read_write.c) from 1991.

Answer (score 2):

The [yggdrasil](https://www.ibiblio.org/pub/historic-linux/distributions/yggdrasil/) tarball from November 1994 has `sys_write` in `/usr/src/linux/fs/read_write.c` (actually gzip'd).

That file has this: *Copyright (C) 1991, 1992 Linus Torvalds* which indicates it was added in 1991 or 1992. There was no version-control system in use at that time, so details are scarce.

Comment: the source file of the file you mendtion has this: `Copyright (C) 1991, 1992  Linus Torvalds` do you have any idea of which version could it be?

Comment: not offhand (and there was no version-control system in use at that time, so details are scarce)

Comment: ok, thank you very very much! would you mind if i add some info to your answers or do you prefer to do it instead of me? i would like to talk about the fact that the file you did mention has that copyright leyend, what suggest that `sys_write` was introduced during those years ...

Comment: go ahead (I have to leave for now)

Answer (score 2):

At the risk of repeating information
that is undoubtedly documented in a million places:

[“Unix Version 6” (or “Unix Sixth Edition”)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_6_Unix)
was the first version of Unix
released outside of AT&T Bell Laboratories (the birthplace of Unix). 
I know this happened by 1975 at the latest. 
I know nothing about versions before that. 
(Chronology note: “Version 7”, naturally, came shortly after “Version 6”. 
Then “System III” and “System V” came long after that.)

The `write` system call was present in Unix Version 6. 
[Here is the `write(II)` man page from Unix Version 6](http://wwwlehre.dhbw-stuttgart.de/~helbig/os/v6/doc/II/write.html);
note that it is dated 8/5/73. 
Here is an [index](http://wwwlehre.dhbw-stuttgart.de/~helbig/os/v6/doc/0/index.html) of all the man pages.

Linux was announced in 1991; see, for example, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Linux). 
[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29882/80216#29886) to the U&L question [Is it true
that the first version of Linux was based on parts of Unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29882/80216)
claims that Linus Torvalds based the Linux system calls
on the Unix man pages,
saying that this information comes from the book [*Just for Fun*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just_for_Fun).

So, the `write` system call was in Unix long before Linux existed.

Comment: First Edition Unix source has been reconstructed from tapes and published.

Comment: @JdeBP: ***First** Edition*? As in from the late ***1960s?*** That could be interesting, and perhaps useful. Can you provide a link?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320133/

Comment: Interesting. There seems to be a sys_write call at line 24 in the C compiler from mid 1972:
https://github.com/DoctorWkt/unix-jun72/blob/master/src/c/c1t.s

Comment: `sys write` can be found in lots of places where you would expect it to be; e.g., [cat.s](https://github.com/DoctorWkt/unix-jun72/blob/master/src/cmd/cat.s) lines 46 and 55; [df.s](https://github.com/DoctorWkt/unix-jun72/blob/master/src/cmd/df.s) lines 8, 12, 16, 22, and 61; etc.; and the most obvious place, [write.s](https://github.com/DoctorWkt/unix-jun72/blob/master/src/lib/write.s) line 17.  I could find only one C file that called `write()`— because there is so little C code! — in [cp.c](https://github.com/DoctorWkt/unix-jun72/blob/master/src/cmd/cp.c) lines 9, 13, 31, 35, 41, 44, and 45.

Comment: However, this question is about when Linux implemented it.