# What's this I hear about First Edition Unix being restored?

Tags: history, historical-unix

[I commented elsewhere](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/319987/minimum-version-for-syscall-write/320004#comment562521_320004) that the source code of First Edition Unix had been restored from tapes.  The response was amazement and a request for more information.

What have people done?  Who did it?  When?  And how?

Answer (score 61):

In 2008–2009 [The Unix Heritage Society](http://www.tuhs.org/) managed to reconstruct the source for First Edition Unix kernel and parts of [the shell](https://superuser.com/a/329479/38062) from various sources, including magnetic tapes and paper documents.  The details were written up and presented at a USENIX conference in 2009.

- Warren Toomey (2009).  "[The Restoration of Early UNIX Artifacts](https://usenix.org/legacy/event/usenix09/tech/full_papers/toomey/toomey.pdf)".  *Proceedings of the 2009 USENIX annual technical conference, San Diego, United States*.  ISBN 978-1-931971-68-3.  p. 273.

There have been other papers.

- Warren Toomey (2010).  "First Edition Unix: Its Creation and Restoration".  *IEEE Annals of the History of Computing*.  **32(3)**. July–September 2010.  DOI: [10.1109/MAHC.2009.55](https://dx.doi.org/10.1109/MAHC.2009.55).  pp. 74–82.

Originally, the source was available on Google Code.  Google Code of course proceeded to then turn up its toes and die, and all that is left there is [a badly-marked up archive](https://code.google.com/archive/p/unix-jun72/).

However, M. Toomey has also made the source available on [his TUHS account on GitHub](https://github.com/DoctorWkt/unix-jun72), as have [many](https://github.com/c3x04/Unix-1st-Edition-jun72) [many](https://github.com/NP95/unix-jun72) [many](https://github.com/xtao/unix-jun72) [many](https://github.com/julian1303/unix-jun72) [many](https://github.com/oogl-import/unix-jun72) [many](https://github.com/DILEEP-YADAV/unix-jun72) [many](https://github.com/madztyles/unix-jun72) [many](https://github.com/dugoh/unix-jun72) [many](https://github.com/bertjwregeer/unix-jun72) [many](https://github.com/search?q=unix-jun72&type=Repositories) other people.

First Edition manuals available in digital form had also been made available.

- Denis M. Ritchie. *[Unix Programmer's Manual November 3, 1971](https://bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/1stEdman.html)*.
- [Unix First Edition Manuals](http://man.cat-v.org/unix-1st/)

In more recent work, Diomidis D. Spinellis of the Athens University of Economics and Business has integrated this and others into [a reconstructed combined GitHub repository encompassing some 40 years of development](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo), from [First Edition here](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/tree/Research-V1-Snapshot-Development) and other Research Unix versions through 386BSD to FreeBSD 11.0.

- Diomidis D. Spinellis (2016-08-11).  "[A repository of Unix history and evolution](http://www.spinellis.gr/pubs/jrnl/2016-EMPSE-unix-history/html/unix-history.html)".  *Empirical Software Engineering*. pp. 1–33.  DOI: [10.1007/s10664-016-9445-5](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10664-016-9445-5).

## Further reading

- [The Heirloom Project](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/index.html)

Comment: The source code (for First Edition and many other early versions) can also be browsed and searched directly on the [TUHS web site](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl).

Comment: Oh and you can read about the reconstruction effort in the [TUHS mailing list archives](http://minnie.tuhs.org/pipermail/tuhs/2008-April/003259.html).

Comment: ... and in the dedicated [mailing list archives](http://minnie.tuhs.org/pipermail/unix-jun72/) too.

Comment: "The single point of failure is now ..." when referring to a distributed version control solution.   =/   Makes brain hurt.

Comment: @tjd Unfortunately, the `git` in GitHub is very often used in the same way as `subversion`

Comment: @DavidTonhofer While folks often use a centralized *workflow* there is tremendous value inherent in each contributor's clone of the repository.